# window.location is very slow to go another page

Tags: javascript

why does window.location take 3 -5 sec to go another page? 
I want to change the page immediately after confirm .

```
<script>
       var a = confirm('Do you want to insert the device specifications now ؟');
       if(a)
       {
       var name = '<?= $items_name ?>';
       window.location = 'mobiles.php?name='+name;
       }else
       {
       return false;
       }
</script>
```

It seems to me location.assign is faster

```
<script> 
var a = confirm('Do you want to insert the device specifications now?');
if(a) {  
  var name = '<?= $items_name ?>'; 
  window.location.assign('mobiles.php?name='+name); 
}
else { 
    return false; 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: what it has to do with Java, retagged

Comment: @mprabhat if you retag you need to retag good. This is JavaScript not PHP!! Thank you Xeon06

Comment: @mprabhat it has nothing to do with PHP either. I retagged properly.

Comment: Downvoted, I think there's no need to say why...

Comment: Have you used a tool like Fiddler/Charles to see where the delay is?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will trigger the page change immediately. If you're experiencing a delay, is is most likely the time your browser is taking to load the new page. You can try optimizing the load time for your new page. You can find various resources on the web for page load time optimizations if you simply use Google.

Comment: i try window.location.assign('mobiles.php?name='+name);

    window.location.assign work faster shank you for replay 
     <script>
         var a = confirm('Do you want to insert the device specifications now ؟);
             if(a)
           {
         var name = '<?= $items_name ?>';
            window.location.assign('mobiles.php?name='+name);
              }else
               {
         return false;
       }
         </script>

Comment: window.location.assign(...) works perfect for me. Thanks.